# GWT DockLayoutPanel + ScrollPanel inside DecoratorPanel as a center

Tags: java, gwt, layout

I have my layout defined like this:

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
    <g:north size="100">
        <g:Label>top</g:Label>
    </g:north>
    <g:center>
        <!-- <g:DecoratorPanel> -->
        <g:ScrollPanel>
            <g:VerticalPanel>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
                <g:Label>center</g:Label>
            </g:VerticalPanel>
        </g:ScrollPanel>
        <!-- </g:DecoratorPanel> -->
    </g:center>
    <g:south size="100">
        <g:Label>bottom</g:Label>
    </g:south>  
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Works fine, but if I wrap `ScrollPanel` with `DecoratorPanel`, scroll never works. What is the problem and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DecoratorPanel` is rendered as a `<table>`, so you should not use it as a direct child of `<g:center>` tag.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get my ScrollPanel wrapped with fancy border.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example, scroll works)
But scrollbar located at right edge of window.

If you dont see it, try to add  or set width of scrollPanel.